# Python function to return strings

Tags: python, function, text

I use a script to retrieve data values from a building automation system (script isnt shown for that) and I am curious to create a function that can return strings based on summary statistics of the data.

Two part question, Im only printing values as shown below but is it possible to return multiple strings (instead of printing) if any of the conditions are TRUE?

This next question maybe silly, but is it possible to create like an empty list to compile/append strings? Im curious to play around with text analytics if I could compile a large amount of data.

***UPDATED CODE BELOW***

```
def check_fans(fansData):

    fan_strings = []

    count = fansData.history.count()
    std = fansData.history.std()
    maxy = fansData.history.max()
    mean = fansData.history.mean()
    low = fansData.history.min()


    if std > 5:
        fluxIssue = f'there appears to be fluctuations in the fan speed data like the PID is hunting, std is {std}, {count}'
        fan_strings.append(fluxIssue)
    if mean > 90:
        meanHigh = f'the supply fan speed mean is over 90% like the fan isnt building static, mean value recorded is {mean}, {count}'
        fan_strings.append(meanHigh)
    if mean < 50:
        meanLow = f'the supply fan speed mean is under 50% like there is duct blockage/looks odd, mean value recorded is {mean}, {count}'
        fan_strings.append(meanLow)

    return fan_strings
```

Comment: just declare an empty string and append to it

Comment: Or make a list to append your strings to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to create like an empty list

Of course; `[]` is a newly created empty list, and then you can give it a name like anything else.

> to compile/append strings?

Sure; use the normal list operations, like `.append`. This solves the original problem as well:

> is it possible to return multiple strings (instead of printing) if any of the conditions are TRUE?

Build up the list of strings you want to return, and then return the list.

(This is, incidentally, a Good Idea; in general you want your functions to return useful data rather than directly printing stuff - that way, the calling code can do something else with that data, and you can *avoid* the printing if there's something better to do.)

Comment: I updated the code portion of my question, this would be an empty string right? And then just append... And return the list? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely set an empty string and use a for loop to record the data. Though I'm imagining what you want to do is cycle through several sets of data and append certain results.

I don't think plugging all of that into a function is the best way to do that.

Maybe change your function to something like:

```
def check_fans(fansData):
   count = fansData.history.count()
   std = fansData.history.std()
   maxy = fansData.history.max()
   mean = fansData.history.mean()
   low = fansData.history.min()


results = [] 

fluxIssue = 'there appears to be fluctuations in the fan speed data like the PID is hunting, std is {}, {}'

meanHigh = 'the supply fan speed mean is over 90% like the fan isnt building static, mean value recorded is {}, {}'

meanLow = 'the supply fan speed mean is under 50% like there is duct blockage/looks odd, mean value recorded is {}, {}'

For data in list_of_data:
    check_fans(data)
    if check_fans.std > 5:
        results.append(fluxIssue.format(check_fans.std, check_fans.count))
    if check_fans.mean > 90:
        results.append(meanHigh.format(check_fans.mean, check_fans.count))
    elif check_fans.mean < 50:
        results.append(meanLow.format(check_fans.mean, check_fans.count))
    else:
        continue

print(results)
```

I would likely recommend using a dictionary though. you'll end up with a  big string of numbers which I don't thinks will be very helpful for any kind of analytics